# Easiest way to validate between two CSV files using python

Tags: python, csv

I have two CSV files, and I would like to validate(find the differences and similarities) the data between these two files.

I am retrieving this data from vertica and because the data is so large I would like to do the validation at CSV level.

Comment: could you provide an example for what you exactly want to do ?

Comment: why don't you want to compare your data sets in vertica __before__ exporting them as CSV files?

Answer (score 1):

[csvdiff](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/csvdiff) allows you to compare the semantic contents of two CSV files, ignoring things like row and column ordering in order to get to what’s actually changed. This is useful if you’re comparing the output of an automatic system from one day to the next, so that you can look at just what’s changed.

Comment: no probs @user840882 ! All the best :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly compare sheets using openpyxl without manually looping on each rows and using your own validation code. 
That depend your aim at performance, if speed is not a requirement, then why not but that will require some additional work.

Instead I would use **pandas** dataframes for any CSV validation needs, if you can add this dependency it should become really easier to compare files while keeping it at a great performance.

Here is a link to complete example:
http://pbpython.com/excel-diff-pandas.html

However, use read_csv() instead of read_excel() to read data from your files.

Comment: this is very useful Retsim, thank you.. !!

Comment: @user840882 Glad it helped !